# Rails + Neglect existing record if it's primary value is stored in different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, very basic stuff I am not trying but not getting option. I am trying to fetch the values of User that do not have scholarship data.

## Student

```
[ id, name, standard ]    
1, John, X
2, Alex, XII
3, James, X
4, Steve, XI
5, Richard, XI
```

## ScholarShip

```
[ id, student_id, type_of_scholarship ]
1, 1,"Edward Scholar"
2, 3,"McVince Scholar"
```

Student has_one ScholarShip as association

Now I am trying to create object of Student records did not have scholarship to create dropdown at UI

Rails : `@student = Student.some_method_to_fetch_those_students_dnt_have_scholarship`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get students which has not scholarship by doing this:-

```
Class Student
    def self.get_students_which_has_not_scholarship
        students = self.all
        scholar_ship_students_ids = Scholarship.pluck(:student_id)
        students.select{ |student| !scholar_ship_students_ids.include?(student.id) }
    end
end
```

Then you can call it like:-

```
@students = Student.get_students_which_has_not_scholarship
```

Answer (score 0):

you want something like

```
Student.joins("LEFT JOIN Scholarship ON Student.id = ScholarShip.student_id").where("ScholarShip.id IS NULL")
```

you can make this a scope on Student and name it whatever you like:

```
scope :without_scholarships, -> {
   joins("LEFT JOIN Scholarship ON Student.id = ScholarShip.student_id").where("ScholarShip.id IS NULL")
}
```

call it as you would a class method

```
Student.without_scholarships
```

This will return a relation that you can chain together, i.e.

```
Student.without_scholarships.order(:grade_point_average)
```

or whatever